# Is durability taken when destroying a boat or minecart?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing a survival world, and I found a mineshaft. I found some minecarts, and mined them. I did not see any "boop" of durability when I hit or destroyed it with my pickaxe. The same thing happened when I destroyed a boat with an axe. So, what is going on, and do you lose tool durability when you mine/destroy a boat or a minecart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a look at the Minecraft Wiki on durability:

> - Axes, pickaxes, and shovels:
>
>   - Breaking a block that breaks instantly counts as **0** uses.
>   - Breaking other blocks counts as **1** use.
>   - Paving a grass block using a shovel to make a grass path counts as **1** use.
>   - Using an axe on a log or wood to strip it counts as **1** use.
>   - Hitting a mob (hostile, neutral or passive) counts as **2** uses.

It could be considered that minecarts are part of the "blocks that break instantly" with the fact that one hit with a pickaxe can break the minecart.

But then again, there's the other argument...

I've found a [bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-187306) about the same issue in Java Edition. It has been confirmed as a bug in Java Edition, so it might be the same in Bedrock Edition too.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think so, because destroying a boat doesn’t take time. It’s basically instant. So no, it shouldn’t take durability.

Comment: I don't agree with that. Can you edit your answer and specify this?